# How to use batch processing in photoshop to divide all images in a folder

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, photoshop-cs5

I am trying to use batch processing in photoshop to parse through a particular folder, take each original image (JPG), divide it in half vertically (2 columns), and save it out to a destination folder as an incrementally numbered TIF. I'm having the worst time figuring out how to put individual actions together to get the result I want. So what I want is:

\Source\IMG1.JPG,IMG2.JPG, IMG3.JPG

converted to

\Destination\IMG001.TIF, IMG002.TIF, IMG003.TIF, IMG004.TIF, IMG005.TIF, IMG006.TIF

Where IMG001.TIF is left side of IMG1.JPG, IMG002.TIF is right side of IMG1.JPG, IMG003.TIF is left side of IMG2.JPG, IMG004.TIF is right side of IMG2.JPG, etc.

I was able to set up one action to take the original image, duplicate it twice, resize one duplicate to 50% on left, one to 50% on right, and then close the original leaving the two (properly) resized images. My problem is how to save those each as a TIF with batch processing, while being able to parse through each source file one at a time, and preserve the incremental numbering scheme overall. I've tried so many variations my head is spinning, and always either overwrite some images, lose all processing, or end up in continuous loops going through the source directory.

Does anyone have suggestions for this? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated (really looking for guidance on how to call the actions I guess)..

Thanks,

Erik

Comment: are you familiar or proficient with javascript, actionscript, and/or vbscript?

Answer (score 2):

There are many utilities for renaming a sequence of files, therefore I believe that a reasonable though not ideal solution is one that generates the right files, in the right order, even if the names are wrong.

Use [this action file](http://www.filedropper.com/set1) and set your Batch dialog like this:

[image]

Of course, change the source and destination folders as needed.

For input files

```
mycat.jpg
mydog.jpg
vacation.jpg
```

the output will be

```
mycat001.jpg
mycat001001.jpg
mydog002.jpg
mydog002002.jpg
vacation003.jpg
vacation003003.jpg
```

From there, any file renaming utility should be able to renumber these sequentially to

```
IMG001.jpg
IMG002.jpg
IMG003.jpg
...
```

You will want to change the Action file to set output quality, etc., but this should serve as a template.